# converting digital length to physical length using reference object

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find actual length of an object, say X, from an image. For that I'm using a reference object , say Y, ( object of known dimensions ). From image while converting pixel length of X to physical length, using reference object dimension , it is consistently resulting in error b/w 1.2 inch to 1.6 inch.

I am using one frame of 60 inch * 48 inch as a reference object and actual object is placed inside the frame.
My formula is actual length of X = pixel length of X * actual length of Y / pixel length of Y.I am using overhead camera of 13 MP. what can be the reason of error ? and how to reduce this within 1 inch ?

Comment: Hi! can you please upload an example image with clear indications of your reference object and the measured object...